# how to test/verify OPTIONS method after disabling on apache2 webserver

Tags: apache-2.2

i have this issue with web application inspection software. the recommendation was to disable `OPTION METHODS` on the webserver.

upon research. i have included this snippet on my `httpd.conf` then restarted the server.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|OPTIONS)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

how can i verify if the code is implemented and will block all OPTIONS request?

i have tried this

`curl --request OPTIONS http://10.1.1.1/mysite`

but all i get is 301 Moved Permantently

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://10.1.1.1/mysite">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.1.1.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using mod_rewrite, you should be able to disable arbitrary methods using the [Limit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limit) or [LimitExcept](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitexcept) directives which are designed to to just what you want.

You can test using [nc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) or [telnet](http://linux.die.net/man/1/telnet) to talk directly to the httpd process

```
$ nc yourhost.tld 80
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Host: yourhost.tld

 (press enter a couple of times here and the server responds)

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Dec 2013 09:16:40 GMT
Server: Apache
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
$
```